# scrollview doesn't scroll up enough to see the rest of views xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview

i wrote this code for a registration page. in some phones, the screen doesn't fit for all the views so i used a scrollview so that the user could scroll down through them. the problem i'm facing is that the scrollview doesn't scroll enough upwards. the button at the end doesn't appear. here is my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="ALNahrainAlphaApp.RegisterPage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ALNahrainAlphaApp;assembly=ALNahrainAlphaApp" 
             >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        
        <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
            <ScrollView.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#0d98ba"
                          Offset="0.2" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </ScrollView.Background>
            <StackLayout>
            
            <Grid>

                <StackLayout>
                   


                    <Frame CornerRadius="50" BorderColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="20,50">
                        <Grid Padding="1" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="0" Margin="0,160">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Frame CornerRadius="20" Margin="0,5" />

                            <controls:CustomEntry
                               
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                x:Name="id"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                Margin="10,5"
                                TextColor="Black"
                       Placeholder="ID"
                                FontSize="16"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                      
                    />


                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <controls:CustomEntry
                                
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                x:Name="firstname"
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                Margin="10,5"
                                TextColor="Black"
                                
                                FontSize="16"
                        Placeholder="First Name"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                      
                    />

                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="2"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <controls:CustomEntry
                            
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                x:Name="lastname"
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                Margin="10,5"
                                TextColor="Black"
                        Placeholder="Last Name"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                                   FontSize="16"
                      
                    />
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="3"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <controls:CustomEntry
                                 FontSize="16"
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                x:Name="role"
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                Margin="10,5"
                                TextColor="Black"
                        Placeholder="Role"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                      
                    />
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="4"  Margin="0,5"/>

                            <controls:CustomEntry
                                   FontSize="16"
                                Grid.Row="4"
                                x:Name="user_name"
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                Margin="10,5"
                                TextColor="Black"
                       
                       Placeholder="Username"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                    />


                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="5"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <controls:CustomEntry
                                   FontSize="16"
                                Grid.Row="5"
                                x:Name="password"
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                Margin="10,5"
                                TextColor="Black"
                        Placeholder="Password"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                      
                    />


                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"      Grid.Row="6">
                                <Label Text="Allow Access" TextColor="Black"  FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="15,5"/>
                                <Switch
                               
                           ThumbColor="Black"
                                    OnColor="White"
                                x:Name="appaccess"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="40,0"
                      
                    />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                    <Button CornerRadius="50" Text="Submit" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"  FontFamily="audiofont" x:Name="save" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="140" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-85" Clicked="save_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Frame CornerRadius="50" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  Padding="-2"  BorderColor="White"  Margin="20,5,20,0">
                    <Image HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" x:Name="userprofile"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

i tried different things, i put the scrollview inside a contentview but i didn't work. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: **1)** Google xamarin ios safe area. **2)** Do you need BOTH the outer Grid and Stacklayout? Test with a simple layout, even if it doesn’t have all you need, get it to work. Then add to it.

Comment: i am using the outer grid in order to overlap the circular frame with the rectangular one. i added the stacklayout because i thought it might help to scroll but i didn't. it seems that the grid is preventing the scrollview from functioning properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add property `RowDefinitions` and define two row for the outer grid.

```
         <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--other code-->
         <Grid>
```

You can refer to the following code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
        <ScrollView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="#0d98ba"
                      Offset="0.2" />
                <GradientStop Color="White"
                      Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollView.Background>
        <StackLayout>

            <Grid>
              <!--add two row here-->

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                

              <StackLayout>


                <Frame CornerRadius="50" BorderColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="20,50">
                        <Grid Padding="1" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="0" Margin="0,160">

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="70" />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Frame CornerRadius="20" Margin="0,5" />

                            <Entry
                           
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            x:Name="id"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Margin="10,5"
                            TextColor="Black"
                   Placeholder="ID"
                            FontSize="16"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                  
                />


                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <Entry
                            
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            x:Name="firstname"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            Margin="10,5"
                            TextColor="Black"
                            
                            FontSize="16"
                    Placeholder="First Name"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                  
                />

                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="2"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <Entry
                        
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            x:Name="lastname"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            Margin="10,5"
                            TextColor="Black"
                    Placeholder="Last Name"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                               FontSize="16"
                  
                />
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="3"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <Entry
                             FontSize="16"
                            Grid.Row="3"
                            x:Name="role"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            Margin="10,5"
                            TextColor="Black"
                    Placeholder="Role"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                  
                />
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="4"  Margin="0,5"/>

                            <Entry
                               FontSize="16"
                            Grid.Row="4"
                            x:Name="user_name"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            Margin="10,5"
                            TextColor="Black"
                   
                   Placeholder="Username"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                />


                            <Frame CornerRadius="20"  Grid.Row="5"  Margin="0,5"/>
                            <Entry
                               FontSize="16"
                            Grid.Row="5"
                            x:Name="password"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            Margin="10,5"
                            TextColor="Black"
                    Placeholder="Password"
                PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                  
                />


                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"      Grid.Row="6">
                                <Label Text="Allow Access" TextColor="Black"  FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="15,5"/>
                                <Switch
                           
                       ThumbColor="Black"
                                OnColor="White"
                            x:Name="appaccess"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Margin="40,0"
                  
                />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                  

                <Button   CornerRadius="50" Text="Submit" FontSize="Medium" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"  FontFamily="audiofont" x:Name="save" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="140" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Margin="0,-85" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Frame CornerRadius="50" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  Padding="-2"  BorderColor="White"  Margin="20,5,20,0">
                    <Image HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" x:Name="userprofile"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Source="grass.png"/>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Margin

```
  <Frame CornerRadius="50" BorderColor="White" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="20,50">
                    <Grid Padding="1" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="0" Margin="0,90">
```

[image]

Comment: yes my margin is  0,40 in the main place. i used 160 just to confirm that the scrollview would scroll as much as needed whatever the margin was. but it didn't. why is that?

Comment: and also whatever the screen size is. when i tried this code on my iphone simulator, when i scroll up to reach the button, the scrollview scrolls back down by itself that i can't even click the button